# What's the difference between a Sole Means Navigation System and a Primary Means Navigation System?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, navigation, avionics, gnss, vor

For bonus points, how you define a supplemental means navigation system?

Comment: Can you give us some context? Are you asking about how they are defined by regulation? If so, for which country or regulator?

Answer (score 2):

Sole means it is the only system, primary implies there is a secondary or even tertiary system, and supplemental means it supplements another system.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just to clarify, a sole means system can function on it's own, while a primary means system requires other systems to aid it in order for it be a reliable means of navigation?

Comment: Not to be rude, but please look up the definitions of sole, primary, and supplemental, and then let us know if you have a specific difficulty relating them to the general subject of aviation.  Better yet, if there is an actual aircraft or navigation system description that you are trying to understand better, if you can quote it we might be able to clarify its performance limitations for you.